# rpmbuild generates RPM in which subdirectory

Tags: linux, rpmbuild

rpmbuild generates RPM under which directory?

I checked the RPMS directory:-

```
[root@tom adil]# ls /usr/src/redhat/
BUILD  RPMS  SOURCES  SPECS  SRPMS
[root@tom adil]# ls /usr/src/redhat/RPMS/
athlon  i386  i486  i586  i686  noarch
[root@tom adil]#
```

How to decide rpmbuild outputs in which of the above sub-directories?
Is it controlled by spec file? What is the default option?

I thought `uname -p` but its not the case probable `uname -i` is used.
Linked to my last question [Difference between "machine hardware" and "hardware platform"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565282/difference-between-machine-hardware-and-hardware-platform)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The binary package is named according to the `%_build_name_fmt` macro. By default this macro contains `%{ARCH}/` at the beginning, so that is where the binary package is placed.

Comment: Thanks. How this ARCH value is determined? i am interested in that.

Comment: The arch of a package is determined by the value passed after the `--target` argument to `rpmbuild` (e.g., `--target noarch`).

Comment: Thanks. This was useful to find out the current format: `rpm --showrc | grep ": _build_name_fmt"`.  Also, readers may be interested to know that they can pass this as an argument to rpmbuild like this example, where I have removed the architecture directory: `rpmbuild --define "_build_name_fmt %%{NAME}-%%{VERSION}-%%{RELEASE}.%%{ARCH}.rpm" …`

Answer (score 2):

Following on from your last comment, by default the RPM will go into the subdirectory that matches the platform you're building on.  You can override this by passing the --target parameter to rpmbuild, but this only applies where valid; for example, you can use --target i386 on an x86_64 system to build a 32-bit RPM, but you can't build a 64-bit RPM on a 32-bit platform.

Comment: Thanks if i dont specify it will go under which dir? `uname -a` gives output "Linux tom 2.6.9-89.ELsmp #1 SMP Mon Apr 20 10:34:33 EDT 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux "

Comment: It will go into either i686 or i386.

Answer (score 0):

The RPM goes to the RPMS folder and the source RPM to the SRPMS. This is not controlled by the spec file - this is convention. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks, that i know. As shown above my RPMS directory has 6 sub-directories: athlon  i386  i486  i586  i686  noarch 
So if i build a RPM, default it will generated under which sub-dir?